# ElasticSearch keyword mapping leads to illegal_state_exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

In a spring boot application when indexing an object into es I get the following exception.

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9299], 
URI [/my_index_name/_doc/1000001_000000004-v2?timeout=5s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [billingperiod] 
of type [keyword] in document with id '1000001_000000004-v2'. Preview of field's value: 
'{enddate=2016-12-31, startdate=2016-10-01}'"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to 
parse field [billingperiod] of type [keyword] in document with id '1000001_000000004-v2'. Preview of 
field's value: '{enddate=2016-12-31, startdate=2016-10-01}'","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception",
"reason":"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:399"}},"status":400}
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:262)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1628)
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: 
Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_state_exception, reason=Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:399]
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:496)
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:407)
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:437)
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:603)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:179)
... 136 common frames omitted
```

The class has a couple of static fields and two instance variables of type `LocalDate` and a view methods one of which is the overridden toString.

The mapping is as follows. Without the mapping the indexing works fine. However, a null_value needs to be configured since the object can be null.

```
    {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "mapStringToKeywordByDefault": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "billingperiod": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "null_value": "anemptystring"
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried to replace `keyword` with `flattened`, however, the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/flattened.html) state: "A string value which is substituted for any explicit null values *within* the flattened object field. Defaults to null, which means null sields are treated as if it were missing." So if the object itself is null it is not working.

Version ElasticSearch 7.10 (cannot be changed)

What is my mistake? What can I do to make that work?

**Update on reply of ilvar:**

With the configuration of your example the index can be created, but null values cannot be found. It needs a mapping for `null_value`. However, without specifying a type for billingperiod it fails:

```
"billingperiod": {
  "properties": {
    "startdate": {"type": "date"},
    "enddate": {"type": "date"}
  },
  "null_value": "anothertry"
}
```

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [billingperiod] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : anothertry]]

With type `flattened` it fails too which is unclear to me since without `type` and `null_value` it works.

```
"billingperiod": {
  "type": "flattened",
  "properties": {
    "startdate": {"type": "date"},
    "enddate": {"type": "date"}
  },
  "null_value": "anothertry"
}
```

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [billingperiod] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {enddate={type=date}, startdate={type=date}}]]

The following mapping works, but does not allow for null entries of the billingperiod itself but only of fields within (e.g. {startdate=2000-01-01,enddate=null} is found but null itself not).

```
"billingperiod": {
  "type": "flattened",
  "null_value": "anothertry"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should properly reflect your data schema so you should have something like:

```
"billingperiod": {
  "properties": {
    "startdate": {"type": "date"},
    "enddate": {"type": "date"}
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with some code samples I tried. Indexing itself can be achieved but I cannot find a combination with which I can search for null values in the index.

Comment: Have you tried `{"bool": {"must_not": {"exists": {"field": "billingperiod"}}}}`?

Comment: Yes, didn't work

Comment: Without `null_value` this query returns `{"billingperiod": {}}`, `{"billingperiod": null}` and `{}` but not `{"billingperiod": {"start_date": "2011-01-01"}}`.